# Could someone please explain OVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have borrowed a query and adapted it for my own purposes, but I don't like doing this when I am not entirely sure what it is doing.  SQL docs are less than descriptive on this clause.  Here is what I borrowed and modified, can you tell me what it is doing basically?

```
(SELECT Id FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            Id
            ,RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY DropStatusId ORDER BY StatusDate DESC) [Rank] 
        FROM 
            [dbo].[tblLHTrackingHistory] [TempHistory]
        WHERE 
            [TempHistory].[DropStatusId] = [DropStatus].[Id]
    ) [TT1] WHERE [Rank] = 1
)
```

Comment: +1 for "don't like doing this when I am not entirely sure what it is doing"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `OVER` clause means you're using analytics (vs say aggregates).  Per the [OVER documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28SQL.90%29.aspx):

> Determines the partitioning and ordering of the rowset before the associated window function is applied.

Unlike aggregates, analytics don't require a `GROUP BY` to be defined.

Answer (score 3):

Great answers so far.
Sometimes a visual example helps:

```
DropStatusId  StatusDate  Rank  
1             2010-02-19  1    <
1             2010-02-18  2
1             2010-02-17  3
2             2010-02-18  1    <
2             2010-02-15  2
2             2010-02-13  3
2             2010-02-12  4
```

The "partition" is the records for a given DropStatusId.

Answer (score 2):

Read [this](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/03/28/60146.aspx), it is pretty straight-forward.
"Credit to Jeff Smith"